# Disabling zoom-level based simplification of GoogleMap polygons

Tags: android, android-mapview, polygon, android-maps-v2

When adding a polygon with a large number of points to a GoogleMap, it automatically simplifies the geometry based on zoom level - I'm seeing jagged edges that are clearly composed of three points, with more of the intermediate points progressively being rendered at closer zoom levels to eventually produce the curve that's in the actual data.

I've searched the documentation and come up short - I don't see any reference anywhere to a simplification / reduction algorithm being used under the hood, but it clearly is, and it's causing problems for us. I suspect it's a hack thrown in to avoid memory issues on older phones, but I'd rather deal with that than have the displayed data be obviously wrong.

I need a way to disable this behavior - has anyone had any experience with this?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to change right now and can only suggest posting a feature request on gmaps-api-issues.

Comment: Thanks. Added a bug ticket here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal&groupby=&sort=&id=5543